# How to extract qr code from whatsapp web with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, data-extraction

I have tried extracting qr code with python and selenium and able to extract but sometimes qr code is not loading.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')  
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find('div', {"class":"_1pw2F"})
print(divs.attrs["data-ref"])
# in whatsapp web, qr code is the value of "data-ref" attribute of div element with class "_1pw2F"
```

sometimes the value of "data-ref" attribute of div element is not loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a delay before you get the page source, as the QRCode is generated async after page load.

Or you can periodically check if the QRCode section exist, stop the checking and get it when it appears.

Answer (score 0):

This code extracts & clones WhatsApp QR code. Someone can use it in headless chrome scenario:

```
            var xpathQR = "//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div";
            var xpathSidePanel = "//*[@id=\"side\"]";

            IWebElement elSidePanel;

            var loopStart = DateTime.Now;
            var loopTimeout = 100;


            do
            {


                try
                {
                    // IWebElement sidePanel = driver.FindElement(By.Id("side"));
                    elSidePanel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathSidePanel));

                    connected = true;

                    // We are online
                    break; // the loop
                }
                catch
                {
                }


                try
                {
                    IWebElement elQR = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathQR));
                    var qrText = elQR.GetAttribute("data-ref");

                    // We are waiting for QR to scan
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(qrText))
                    {
                        // Generate QR 
                        QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator();
                        QRCoder.QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrText, QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                        QRCoder.QRCode qrCode = new QRCoder.QRCode(qrCodeData);
                        System.Drawing.Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
                        pictureQR.Image = qrCodeImage;

                        buttonLaunchWhatsApp.Visible = false;
                        labelQR.Visible = true;
                        pictureQR.Visible = true;


                    }

                }
                catch { }




                // WhatsApp not loaded yet, wait
                Sleep(1);

            } while (DateTime.Now < loopStart.AddSeconds(loopTimeout) && !terminating);
```